# Can pure php file redirect to laravel page?

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect my page from pure php file to laravel file.
Is there any way to do so?

index.php

```
< a href="(laravel_file_here) " >Welcome </a>
```

Comment: As in you want PHP to generate a URL to a given Laravel page or you want PHP to actually return a redirect?

Comment: You want to say - Redirect to laravel route ?

Comment: i just wondering if php file in public folder can go any blade @Rwd

Comment: @ArunVerma yeah..

Comment: If you will put laravel route url in href, it should work or use php header function to redirect

Comment: @ArunVerma can u give an example, im new in laravel

Comment: In your laravel's web.php route file you should have some routes like `/` or `/welcome`. You don't need to serve blade template , just make a route and pass it's url in your href attribute. But i wonder where is laravel's base index.php file cause you named your pure php file, `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

In public folder suppose you have static_website.php -

```
<a href='/login'>Go to Login Page</a>
```

In Laravel routes file located at routes/web.php you can add

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
return view('login');   // located in resources/views
})->name('login');
```

This will take you to login page if you click on Go to Login Page in static_website.php page